# How do I save and/or quit in Silent Hill 2 HD?

Tags: xbox-360, silent-hill-2

I am playing Silent Hill 2 from the Silent Hill HD Collection available for the X360. Simply put, I can't find a way to save or to quit to the main menu.

Now I have played similar type of games before and some of them have fixed save points (like Deadspace). I am wondering if this one does as well. So far I haven't been able to find them.

There is also the question of quitting the game. How do I do that? I can't find it anywhere in the Start button menu.

Since I can't save, I've had to leave my Xbox on all day!

If this is classified as two questions, I am most happy to split this into two separate question threads.

Comment: Really no one knows?

Comment: It usually takes a few hours *at least* to get an answer to a game that isn't Skyrim or Diablo or Portal around here, but answers usually do come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save points in Silent Hill 2 look like red pieces of paper - http://uk.faqs.ign.com/articles/121/1215833p1.html - heres a list of where they all are.

Straight from IGN:
"You may notice that there is no "Quit" option while playing Silent Hill. Maybe you want to go back to a previous save, or maybe you want to play a different file. There's no "Load" option either! Press and Hold the four shoulder buttons, START, and BACK simultaneously to return to the main menu of Silent Hill 2 or Silent Hill 3.

However, if you want to go back to the Silent Hill HD Collection menu to choose a different game or different set of voices, you'll have to completely quit out of the game and restart it."

First result on google, c'mon man. Try harder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just for your info, I found the answer right after posting this. I just wanted to see if anyone would post an answer. By the way I have tried this method to quit, but it hasn't worked for me (by the four shoulder buttons, I assume it's LB RB LT RT.) I will try again tonight, maybe I didn't do it right.

Comment: Let me know how it goes/if you find a way to quit!!

Comment: I got it. I misunderstood IGN's instructions. I thought they meant - hold down the four shoulder buttons, hit start then hit back. No no. It's 'hold down all six of the buttons.' at the same time. I edited your answer slightly. Hope that's ok.